# Clicking/Expanding and SVG element with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, dom

I am trying to click an SVG html element on a webpage. It is organized like this:

```
<div class="relative cursor-pointer">
    <span class="Popover-module_popoverContainer__2JyDf">
        <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
         fill="currentColor" class="text-20 mr-16 cursor-pointer" data-testid="cloud-download" 
         aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" 
         style="font-size: 16px; vertical-align: -0.175em;">
         <path d="M10 9a.5.5 0 0 1 .492.41l.008.09v3.793l.646-.647.07-.057a.5.5 0 0 1 
             .695.695l-.057.07-1.5 1.5-.07.057a.5.5 0 0 1-.568 0l-.07-.057-1.1.5-.057-.07a.5.0 
             0 1 0-.568l.057-.07.07-.057a.5.5 0 0 1 .568 0l.07.057.646.647V9.5A.5.5 0 0 1 10 
             9zM8.465 1c2.346 0 4.296 1.766 4.625 4.08l.016.138.083.044a3.603 3.603 0 0 1 
             1.805 2.935l.006.208c0 1.92-1.452 3.487-3.307 3.59L11.5 12v-1c1.386 0 2.5-1.153 
             2.5-2.595a2.597 2.597 0 0 0-1.563-2.4.5.5 0 0 1-.304-.435C12.032 3.57 10.42 2 
             8.465 2 6.585 2 5.01 3.46 4.813 5.368a.5.5 0 0 1-.462.448C3.034 5.908 2 7.036 2 
             8.405c0 1.378 1.044 2.502 2.36 2.59l.165.005H8.5v1H4.525C2.575 12 1 10.388 1 
             8.405c0-1.695 1.155-3.13 2.723-3.502l.153-.033.007-.037c.414-2.127 2.207-3.727 
             4.365-3.828L8.465 1z"fill-rule="evenodd">
       </path>
      </svg>
  </span>
</div>
```

Cllicking this element manually with my mouse spawns a div on the document that displays a small menu. I have tried the following:

1 - Setting aria-expanded = true

```
document.getElementsByClassName('text-20 mr-16 cursor-pointer')[0].ariaExpanded = true;
document.getElementsByClassName('text-20 mr-16 cursor-pointer')[0].setAttribute('aria- 
expanded', true);
```

2 - clicking on the div, span, and svg

```
document.getElementsByClassName('relative cursor-pointer')[23].click();
document.getElementsByClassName('Popover-module_popoverContainer__2JyDf')[9].click();
document.getElementsByClassName('text-20 mr-16 cursor-pointer')[0].click();
```

3 - dispatching mousedown and mouseover events on div, span, and svg

```
var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents')
var evt2 = document.createEvent('MouseEvents')
evt.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, 
false, 0, null);
evt2.initMouseEvent('mouseover', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, 
false, 0, null);
document.getElementsByClassName('relative cursor-pointer')[23].dispatchEvent(evt)
document.getElementsByClassName('relative cursor-pointer')[23].dispatchEvent(evt2)
document.getElementsByClassName('Popover-module_popoverContainer__2JyDf'[9].dispatchEvent(evt)
document.getElementsByClassName('Popover-module_popoverContainer__2JyDf') 
[9].dispatchEvent(evt2)
document.getElementsByClassName('text-20 mr-16 cursor-pointer')[0].dispatchEvent(evt)
document.getElementsByClassName('text-20 mr-16 cursor-pointer')[0].dispatchEvent(evt2)
```

I am not sure what else to try to expand this dang menu, I would appreciate any help or insight!

Comment: Thanks you for posting code. But please update your question with a [mcve] so we can actually see your code in action. Preferably using a Stack Snippet.